# LINQPad script fails using lprun, works otherwise, need steps to diagnose the issue

Tags: linq, console-application, linqpad

Some environment details:
LINQPad v4.47.02(AnyCPU)
OS Name Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard
Version 6.2.9200 Build 9200
System Type x64-based PC

I am trying to figure out how I might diagnose an issue I am encountering when launching a script via the lprun.exe command line utility. When I run the script from the IDE interactively it runs and completes without any exceptions.

When the same script is run under the same user from the command line using: lprun.exe

I get this output.

c:\SQLTasks\Linqpad\Demographics\Demo_GenerateDemographicsSubset.linq(880,20) :
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char?'

Due to how LINQPad compiles the script I cant easily locate the area in my script that might be causing this and I'd really like to know if possible what mechanisms might allow it to work interactively and fail from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the discussion on the LINQPad forum: http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/437/lprun-exe-runtime-error-doesn-t-hapen-when-script-is-run-from-linqpad-ide#latest

Edit: this was due to a bug in how LINQPad reads configuration settings in command-line mode. The bug was fixed as of v4.48.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.